# JVM Object Allocation

Tags: object, memory, reference, jvm, allocation

How can I output information regarding object allocations in the JVM? Specifically, I wanted to output the thread ID, object ID, object size, and the number of object references in that object, each time there's an allocation and save it to a textfile. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can profile the application with VisualVM. You can save snapshots at any arbitrary time. Im not sure if its exactly what you want, but it seems pretty close.